# What is the difference between GMM-style instruments and IV-style instruments in GMM estimation via xtabond2 or plm?

Tags: r, panel-data, stata, instrumental-variables, generalized-moments

My question refers to the implementation of GMM estimators, e.g., in the package `xtabond2` for Stata or package `plm` in `R`, function `pgmm`. I understand that the fundamental idea of GMM is to instrument endogeneous variables via their own lags. In the description or their packages, the authors distinguish between 'GMM-style' and 'IV-style' instruments (or 'GMM instruments' and 'normal instruments'). See p. 107-108 in [Roodman (2009)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0900900106) for xtabond2 and the help entry for the `formula` argument in `plm::pgmm()`.

Yet I am not familiar with this distinction. Is it just the case that 'GMM-style' instruments are internal instruments (lags) and 'IV-style' instruments are the original variables themselfes (or external variables)?

In particular, I feel uncomfortable to use the three-part-formula in `R` since I am forced to distinguish between 'GMM-style' and 'IV-style' instruments in the second and third part of the formula when estimating a model using `plm::pgmm()`.